# How Can I specify in my Table that I cannot have two same values in 3 columns with unique or other commands?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unique-key

I have a Reservation table and I want to make sure to do not have two reservations for the same room in the same hotel on the same date.

I wrote below query for the Table.

```
Create table resevations
(
    hotel_id varchar(10),
    cus_id varchar(10),
    room_id varchar(10),
    date_from date,
    date_to date,
    primary_key(hotel_id,customer_id,date_from),
    unique(hotel_id,room_id,date_from)
)
```

I am not sure the combination of columns in unique can do it or not.

Comment: Would you consider changing your table design? I might have an idea but that would require changing your table structure.

Comment: Why don't you try writing a trigger for this?

Comment: What you have allows over-booking and other ugly situations.  Having just `date` (instead of `date_from` and `date_to`) makes it easy to constrain the situation, but you need multiple rows to specify a multi-day reservation.  Which part do you want to make easy??

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to handle validation manually. Using unique or keys will not work because you need to validate on a date range, not just the start date, so a reservation for the room from 2018-02-01 to 2018-02-09 will not stop you reserving a room from 2018-02-03 to 2018-02-07, they overlap totally, but the dates are different.

```
SELECT 1 FROM resevations
WHERE (({startDate} BETWEEN date_from AND date_to OR {endDate} BETWEEN date_from AND date_to)
OR (date_from BETWEEN {startDate} AND {endDate} OR date_to BETWEEN {startDate} AND {endDate}))
AND hotel_id = {hotelID} AND room_id = {roomID} LIMIT 1
```

Fill in the curly braces with the reservation you are trying to make, this will return 1 (true) if it overlaps an existing reservation, or no results if it does not overlap. Once you have that returned you either error or you save the reservation.

As suggested by **Paul Spiegel**, there is a much simpler where clause for this query, where you just check that np reservations for that room begin before your end date and end after your start date, one of which would need to be true of any overlapping reservations.

```
SELECT 1 FROM resevations
WHERE date_from <= {endDate} AND date_to >= {startDate}
AND hotel_id = {hotelID} AND room_id = {roomID} LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The question is tagged as mysql. So you should use `LIMIT 1` (at the end of the statement) instead of `TOP 1`. However - you query won't help if `{startDate}` and `{endDate}` are both outside the range.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes it will help if both are outside the range. If the query returns 1, then you cannot create a reservation, if the query does not return 1, then you can. I do a very similar thing with MsSql for checks on my systems. You use the scalar result (1 or null) converted to a boolean in whatever system is accessing the database, to determine if an overlapping reservation exists.

Comment: You have a row in the DB with `(2018-02-05, 2018-02-07)`. Now you want to reserve the room for `(2018-02-04, 2018-02-08)`. Your query won't find the overlap because neither `2018-02-04` nor `2018-02-08` are in the range of `(2018-02-05, 2018-02-07)`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Ahh I see what you mean now, yes you will have to go both ways. Made the change to check both ways.

Comment: However - the short way is `date_from <= {endDate} AND date_to >= {startDate}`. But for hotel room reservations you would usually use `<` and `>` - since you can check in on the same day as another customer cheks out.

Answer (score 0):

By definition **a primary key is unique**.
So in your case i think having a composed primary key `(hotel_id, room_id, cutomer_id, date)` should do the trick.
this means a reservation is unique for one customer at one hotel and one room at one date.
hope this helps

Comment: yes that is correct. But do you think i will not get any duplicate error if I just have same room_id?

Comment: @ChristianoMoshar No your primary key is the combination of those three columns, if all three are unique it will throw an error.

Comment: oh now i see, i think this is more of a design thing, maybe you can tie the room to one client, by having a foreign key in the room referencing a client

Comment: This would only work if you have one row for every reserved date. But the table is using a date range per reservation. You can't avoid a range overlap by a unique constraint.

Comment: yes that is correct i didn't pay attention to that. i think @Andrew covers this very well in his answer

Comment: That PK allows multiple customers to reserve the same room on the same date -- not a good situation.